# How do I import .onepkg file into one note for windows 10?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

I exported the .onepkg file from onenote 2016 but cannot import into onenote (version Version 16001.11727.20076.0) for windows 10. Tried to move it to onedrive but it was not possible to open it. How do I import it to one note for windows 10?

Comment: Did you try [this procedure](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onenote-mso_win10/onenote-importing-onepkg-file-need-365/ecfd3fbb-d2f2-4de1-8f81-31b22c092b98)? Please [edit] the question and show us details of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still struggling with this annoying problem, the best way I found was to open the .onepkg file as a local notebook in Onenote 2016, then use File -> Share to move it to the cloud.

Once that's complete, you can open it in Onenote 10. Annoying - maybe one day Microsoft will implement all the features that Onenote 2016 has in Onenote 10 but, until then, this is one of the many things that Onenote 10 can't do.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use Onenote's import website at https://www.onenote.com/notebooks/exportimport?toImport=true

The only annoyance is that it expects a folder instead of a .onepkg file, however, onepkg is just a zip file containing the onenote files that would otherwise be in a folder. So you need to :

1. Rename the .onepkg file to have a .zip extension
2. Unzip the file into a folder
3. Upload the folder to the [OneNote import page](https://www.onenote.com/notebooks/exportimport?toImport=true)
4. It sometimes takes a while for everything to be ready, particularly for large files, so be patient

Comment: I would like to add that in step "1" the .onepkg file shall be renamed to .cab file and not .zip.

Answer (score 0):

In OneNote, go to File > Open > Browse and select the .onepkg file